# why not working blob/arrayBuffer on react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am sending a request for an mp3 file. But there is a difference between node.js and react native.

**Node.js/React Native Code:**

```
fetch(url).then(async response => {
    console.log(await response.arrayBuffer());
});
```

**Node.JS Response Log**

```
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <ff fb 90 c4 00 bb ... 13692 more bytes>,
  byteLength: 13792
}
```

**React Native Response Log:**

```
[]
```

Even though it is the same code, the outputs are different. I couldn't understand the reason. What should I do to get like pure nodejs output in React native?